# jQuery mobile 1.3.0 and jQuery validation

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using phonegap with jquery mobile, version 1.3.0, recently launched along with jquery validation ( tried two versions, 1.11 and 1.9 ) and I'm getting a problem with textbox validation. The issue is that the error message is put inside the textbox and it looks ugly. With jquery mobile 1.2.0 everything works fine. I found the problem, don't know how to fix it elegantly.

Code with jquery mobile 1.2.0:

```
<label for="phone">Telefon nummer:</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" class="phone ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset error" value=""><label for="phone" class="error" style="">Telefonnummer skal oplyses</label>
```

Code with jquery mobile 1.3.0:

```
<div class="ui-input-text ui-shadow-inset ui-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-body-c"><input type="text" name="phone" class="phone ui-input-text ui-body-c error" value=""><label for="phone" class="error" style="">Telefonnummer skal oplyses</label></div>
```

As you can see in jquery mobile 1.3.0 they put a div wrapper. How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Found a solution, quite elegant :) . Place this inside the validate function options:

```
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

            error.insertAfter( element.parent() );

        }
```

Comment: I gave you some credits, it looks like your own answer lead to a solution!

Answer (score 4):

Great! I've done an adjustment, because this is just valid for input, not for select, textarea, etc when using JQM 1.3.0.

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    if (element.is("input") && !element.is('input[type="hidden"]'))
                        error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                    else
                        error.insertAfter(element);
```